# how to have perl get https website links to trigger cron job

Tags: perl, https, cron

Currently I have a perl script to trigger a cron job on multiple websites however the script is only working for http and not for https. In other words when the script tries to trigger a link on a domain with an SSL certificate, the cron never gets triggered.  What is required to trigger the https cron URL?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Enter domains, one per line.
#
# They do not have to be indented.
#
# Do not use an '#' on the beginning of your domains.
#
# Enter domains below next line: (without #)
my @domains = qw/#############################

    #www.example.com
    #www.example.com
    #www.example.com

###############_END_OF_DOMAINS_###############/;

my $num_domains = 200; # number of domains
my $cycle_time  = 900; # seconds per cycle

# So if $num_domain=200 and $cycle_time=900,
# there will be 4.5 seconds between sites.

# Nothing below here to service.....
#############################################################################
#############################################################################
#############################################################################
#############################################################################

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use constant DEBUG => 0;

my $time_wait  = $cycle_time / $num_domains;

my @stdin = -t STDIN
    ? ()
    : grep !/^$/, map { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; s/\#.*?$//; $_ } <STDIN>
;

for my $site ( grep !/^\s*\#/, @domains, @stdin ) {
    chomp $site;

    print "contacting: $site\n" if DEBUG;
    my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
             PeerHost   => $site,
             PeerPort   => 'http(80)',
             Proto      => 'tcp',
             Type       => SOCK_STREAM,
             Timeout    => 10,
    );

    unless ( defined $sock ) {
        warn "Couldn't connect to $site: $!\n" if DEBUG;
        next;
    }

    #Example target:
    # http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron

    print $sock
        "GET /index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=cron HTTP/1.0\n" .
        "Host: $site\n\n"
    ;

    # wait for response...
    while (defined( $_ = scalar <$sock> )) {
        # we dont care what it said...
        print 'recv: ', $_ if DEBUG;
    }
    print "\ndone\n" if DEBUG;
    $sock->close;

}
continue {
    print "sleeping $time_wait seconds\n" if DEBUG;
    select( undef, undef, undef, $time_wait );
}

__END__
```

Comment: Where is the code for doing the HTTPS request? You've only shown us the HTTP requesting code

Comment: And possibly more pertinent, why are you doing the request "by hand" and not using something like the module LWP which does HTTP (and HTTPS) requests?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the problem is because you're always configuring your socket object to use the HTTP port (`PeerPort => 'http(80)'`). The HTTPS port is 443, not 80.

But I have no idea why you would write code like this using low-level socket programming. You would be far better advised to look at something like [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) (you will also want to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) for HTTPS support).